# setImageResource inside custom ArrayAdapter caused java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

all code working fine:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts_detail_row_layout, parent, false);
    ImageView smsLogo = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.sms_logo);
    smsLogo.setClickable(true);
    smsLogo.setTag(position);
    if (contactsRow.isSMSApproved == true) smsLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.messages_green);
    else smsLogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.messages_red);
```

until that row:

```
smsLogo.setImageResource(....)
```

LogCat:

> 10-29 22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 10-29 22:46:34.006:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   com.callsfreecalls.android.ContactsDetailArrayAdapter.getView(ContactsDetailArrayAdapter.java:107)
>   10-29 22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409) 10-29
>   22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at
>   android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
>   10-29 22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127) 10-29
>   22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 10-29 22:46:34.006:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
>   10-29 22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381) 10-29
>   22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 10-29 22:46:34.006:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   10-29 22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) 10-29
>   22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 10-29 22:46:34.006:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
>   10-29 22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250) 10-29
>   22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313) 10-29 22:46:34.006:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839) 10-29
>   22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at
>   android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859) 10-29
>   22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-29
>   22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 10-29 22:46:34.006:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 10-29
>   22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-29
>   22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 10-29 22:46:34.006:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>   10-29 22:46:34.006: E/AndroidRuntime(935):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

row_layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sms_logo"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/messages_green" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/callLogo"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/callbuttonred" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactsDetailData"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-43dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:shadowColor="#FFFFFFFF"
    android:shadowDx="1"
    android:shadowDy="1"
    android:shadowRadius="1"
    android:text="+380674878717"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#FF64396F" />
```

this is code creation:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_detail);
    bar = ((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressContactDetailsUpdate));
    bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    contactsDetailsForUsing = this;
    adapterDetails = new ContactsDetailArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.activity_contacts_detail_row_layout);
    lvContactDetails = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listContactsDetailView);
    lvContactDetails.setAdapter(adapterDetails);
```

Comment: Post your xml for `activity_contacts_detail_row_layout`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is in inflating the layout:

```
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts_detail_row_layout, parent, false);
```

I'm not sure but `parent` might be null. Try to use this:

```
View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts_detail_row_layout, null);
```

UPDATE:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <!-- your three views: -->
    <ImageView  .... />
    <ImageView  .... />
    <TextView   .... />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: unfortunately, same result for     View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_contacts_detail_row_layout, null);

Comment: Does your xml has a root layout? I think it should. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: i was using example to programming it. can u post some code to show me, how i can add root layout to row layout?

Comment: of course i have LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapperContactDetails"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" > - i just keep it out

Answer (score 0):

contactsRow.isSMSApproved - isSMSApproved was null. For me was surprise, that primitives must initialized in java...

Comment: This is odd! Anyway, Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @iturki first issue was fixed, but memory issue started. can u suggest something?

Comment: I suggest you start a new question and not changing the scope of this one. It will be clearer.

Comment: @iturki i can't SOF not allow it

Comment: Yes they do allow. Your question changed COMPLETELY to the point [where existing answers don't fit at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94446/editing-a-question-and-asking-a-completely-different-question).